# How to run kubectl on Jenkins that runs on Kubernetes with Kubernetes Plugin installed

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, kubectl

I have an application packaged in a helm chart. And I have Jenkins CI that runs on Kubernetes cluster. I would like to release my app using Jenkins Declarative Pipeline. For this purpose I installed a Jenkins Kubernetes Plugin.

I have the following config for Kubernetes Plugin:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yaml '''
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: jenkins-ci
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: jenkins-admin
          containers:
          - name: helm
            image: alpine/helm:3.10.2
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
          - name: kubectl
            image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
        '''
      retries 2
    }
  }

...
}
```

It works fine:

```
    stage('Pull helm chart') {
      steps {
        container('helm') {
          sh "helm pull ..."
        }
      }
    }
```

But the following doesn't work:

```
    stage('Create Docker Registry secret') {
      steps {
        container('kubectl') {
          sh 'kubectl create ...'
        }
      }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I run "kubectl" command from the Jenkins Pipeline?

Thanks for any help and ideas.

Comment: which error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

Add securityContext in your yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000 # default UID of jenkins user in agent image
  containers:
  - name: maven
    image: maven:3.8.1-jdk-8
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
```

As per the Kubernetes plugin configuration in https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/#plugin-content-pipeline-sh-step-hangs-when-multiple-containers-are-used "this happens when UID of the user in jnlp container differs from the one in another container(s). All containers you use should have the same UID of the user, also this can be achieved by setting securityContext".